# Flutter Google Sign In Error Not Being Caught

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using google sign in and firebase to integrate authentication to my app. However I am facing the problem that, when I cancel the sign in (in the sense that I dismiss the popup), I get a

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_canceled, com.google.GIDSignIn, The user canceled the sign-in flow.))
```

To my knowledge this is supposed to occur, though I am facing the problem that I am not able to catch the error. Here are a few ways in which I have tried to catch this error:

```
Future loginWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    var account;

    try {
      account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('\n\n\n\n\n AN ERROR OCCURED \n\n\n\n\n');
      print(e.message);
    }

    final AuthResult result = await _auth
        .signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
            idToken: (await account.authentication).idToken, accessToken: (await account.authentication).accessToken));
    setState(() {
      _firestore.collection('Users').document('${result.user.uid}').setData({
        'Profile Picture': result.user.photoUrl,
        'Name': result.user.displayName,
        'Email ID': result.user.email,
        'Phone Number': result.user.phoneNumber,
      });
      isAuthenticating = true;
    });
    if (result.user.phoneNumber == null) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => PhoneRegistrationScreen(
            result: result,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

It doesn't print anything when the error occurs.
I have also tried to catch the error with the catchError() callback :

```
account = await googleSignIn.signIn().catchError((error) {
      print('AN ERROR OCCURED');
    });
```

Again, it doesn't print anything when the error occurs.

Thanks a lot guys, and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: post the whole stack trace of the error

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this error and, I have found out that the `.catchError()` callback wasn't being called in the debug mode (which is when you click the `Run->Start Debugging` button in VSCode).

However, when you type in flutter run -d , then, the `.catchError()` method gets called back as it is not in debug mode.

To get your preferred simulator's code paste this line of code in the terminal:

```
instruments -s devices
```

If that doesn't work, you can also try pasting this:

```
xcrun simctl list
```

The  `.catchError()` method will get called unlike before and the code inside that will get executed as expected!

Additionally, the app won't crash anymore with a `PlatformException()` and instead you will get a log like this one:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

I have been facing this problem in Google Sign In too, in which the `.catchError()` was not being called!

In conclusion, if you have some error with handling errors in Firebase Authentication, you should first try to first run in through the terminal. Thanks, and I hope this helps!